# Excel IF show picture

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have a list of codes in sheet 1 (COLUMN A - No of category, COLUMN B - empty)

In the second sheet i have two columns (COLUMN A - No of category, COLUMN B - graphic)

How do I use `VLOOKUP` or any other function to find the matching category and display the appropriate image in the COLUMN B of sheet 1.

I haven't really tried much because I've got no clue of how to do it.

[image]

Comment: `I haven't really tried much because I've got no clue of how to do it.` This is a commonly asked question. Do a search in Google and you will get plenty of examples...

Answer (score 0):

Keep your current VLOOKUP() returning the name.  Next to this have all the pictures stacked up one on top of another (like playing cards in a deck).  Have all the pictures hidden (not visible).  Have an event macro that:

1.detects when VLOOKUP returns a new name
2.makes the picture for that name visible

Ref:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/is-it-possible-to-get-a-vlookup-to-return-a/6b197d2a-e3a8-4933-bde5-64ad78081249?msgId=7ac2b72c-b72d-4369-bdb6-93b774e90b1c

Answer (score -1):

This shows another approach for looking up pictures,
each picture requires a named range assigend to it, 
and then a copied picture acts as a frame, where the content is amended to be an indirect reference to the source pictures.

There is an example file you can download to see how this works

http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?279-VLOOKUP-for-Pictures